# Default/Index route clashing with an existing folder causing 403

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a legacy page that I've just converted to MVC - from "/content/Default.aspx" to "/content/Index". The content folder also contains css files etc.

IIS is attempting to list the folder contents when the default route is requested and returns a 403 response code.

Is there a non-hacky way to get around this. Right now, I'm rewriting the URL in the .htaccess file to use the 'Index' view but would prefer not to do this.

Here's the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Content",
    "content/{action}",
    new { controller = "Content", action = "Index" }
);
```

Here's the hack that I'm currently using:

```
RewriteRule ^/content/(\?.*)?$ /content/Index$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is a good question, but I don't think the solution exists. The reason being that **you probably shouldn't be doing it this way**. The whole MVC framework assumes that when a request is made, either a directory, a file or a controller is expected. In this case, `/content/` is both a real directory **and** a controller. For this reason, any "solution" is going to be a bit of a hack.